# Update Hyperlink In Gridview not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Gridview is not working when user click on the link. User is supposed to be directed to another page when clicked on the link and on the second page, there is a text box that will allow user to update.

this is my code for grid view:

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField = "status" HeaderText = "Status"  HtmlEncode = "true"  ItemStyle-Width="150px" > 
       <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
 </asp:BoundField>
 <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" Text="Click"  CommandName="Select"  HeaderText="Details"   />     
 <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Update" Text="update?" CommandName="GridView1_RowUpdated" />
```

code behind:

```
 Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdated(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdatedEventArgs)
    Dim cr_number As String = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(0).Text
    Response.Redirect("upddetail.aspx?id=" + cr_number)
End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming you change it to a HyperLink, when you click the hyper link it will leave the page, and you'll never get to the GridView1_RowUpdated event.

Comment: @mason so how i want to change it?

Comment: I don't know. Depends on what you want to do. The way I'd do it is pop up a jQuery UI Dialog with an edit window instead of using `ButtonField` etc. But that's just me.

Comment: @mason i not familiar with the Jquery but ,i sometime use jQuery but now the requirement need i update the  data at the second page from the gridview at the first page.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand this, so please read carefully: when you leave a page via a HyperLink, the original GridView is gone, because that entire Page context is gone. Instead of thinking of it as "I need to update the GridView" approach it with the mindset of "I need to update the data in the database, and I need to find a good UI to do it with".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are set the `CommandName` as `GridView1_RowUpdated` you can use `GridView1_RowCommand` event as below

```
  Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)

    If e.CommandName = "GridView1_RowUpdated" Then
       Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
      Dim cr_number As String = GridView1.Rows(index).Cells(0).Text
      Response.Redirect("upddetail.aspx?id=" + cr_number)
    End If

  End Sub
```

in your aspx page set `onrowcommand` as below

```
 <asp:gridview id="GridView" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
```

**instead of all above you can use `hyperlinkfield`**

```
<asp:hyperlinkfield text="Update?"
            datanavigateurlfields="Id"
            datanavigateurlformatstring="~\upddetail.aspx?id={0}"          
            headertext="Update"
            target="_blank" />
```

Comment: i have already ,fix by your instruction but still it noting hapen but it give an error like this If e.CommandName = "GridView1_RowCommand" Then
            Dim cr_number As String = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(0).Text
            Response.Redirect("upddetail.aspx?id=" + cr_number)
        End If

Comment: Error : {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} error start line :             Dim cr_number As String = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(0).Text

Comment: you may not have selected rows, pls check my updated `GridView1_RowCommand` method

Comment: what the purpose of  datanavigateurlfields="Id". it was id filed or cr_number?

Comment: that is what you need to send to upddetail page, if you need cr_number as query string id value, then use that as `datanavigateurlfields`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50831/discussion-between-damith-and-kolapopo)

Comment: Yeah it working . TQ hehe ;) using hyperlink then change the datanavigateurlfields="Id" to "cr_number"

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ButtonField` not an actual hyperlink. When user clicks on this there will be a postback to your original page and it will not navigate to another page. Try using `HyperLink`.

Comment: it working now when i use the hyperlink tq for your suggestion ;0